# Objects spawn randomly in Flash actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I am creating a game that a sheep need to jump or crouch to avoid obstacles.
I had create 2 types of obstacles but they come in a constant speed.
Sometimes the 2 obstacles come together make it impossible to avoid. Is there any way to change this?
Can I make the 2 obstacles come in randomly in a random speed?Here is my code.`

```
    hole_mc.visible = false;
bird_mc.visible = false;

playhotarea_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeInstructionBox);

function removeInstructionBox(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    playhotarea_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeInstructionBox);
    instructionbox_mc.visible = false;
    instructiontext_mc.visible = false;
    playbtn_mc.visible = false;
    playbtntext_mc.visible = false;
    sheep_mc.sheepIN_mc.visible = false;
    sheep_mc.gotoAndPlay("sheepwalk");
    treebg_mc.gotoAndPlay("bgloop");
    hole_mc.visible = true;
    bird_mc.visible = true;
    timer.start();
}


hole_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, holeMove);

function holeMove(event:Event):void {
    if (hole_mc.x>= -200) {
        hole_mc.x -=7;
    }else{
        hole_mc.x=1080;
        trace("hole loops");
    }
}

bird_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, birdMove);

function birdMove(event:Event):void {
    if (bird_mc.x>= -200) {
        bird_mc.x -=10;
    }else{
        bird_mc.x=1080;
        trace("bird loops");
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitHole);

function hitHole(event:Event):void{
    if (sheep_mc.hitTestObject(hole_mc)){
        gotoAndStop("GameOver");
        hole_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, holeMove);
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitHole);
        bird_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, birdMove);
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitBird);
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitBird);

function hitBird(event:Event):void{
    if (sheep_mc.hitTestObject(bird_mc)){
        gotoAndStop("GameOver");
        bird_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, birdMove);
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitBird);
        hole_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, holeMove);
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitHole);
    }
}


var currentSecond:Number = 0; 
var delay:Number = 1000; 
var timer:Timer = new Timer(delay);

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerEventHandler);

function timerEventHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{
   currentSecond++; 
   trace(currentSecond);
   score_txt.text = String(currentSecond + " s");
}

`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always avoid spawning things in the same place by testing for "collision" before you create (or in your case, move) the new object. You should do the testing in whatever class has a reference to all the objects on the screen. In this case, the class you posted has references to the hole and bird, which are the two objects you want to NOT have the same x value.

Try something along the lines of:

```
function birdMove(event:Event):void {
if (bird_mc.x>= -200) {
    bird_mc.x -=10;
}else{
    if(hole_mc.x > 1000){ // See notes below
        bird_mc.x=1080;
        trace("bird loops");
    }}}
```

I put 1000 under the assumption that you would want a little bit of space between the two obstacles. If you're only worried about them being EXACTLY on top of each other, then you can just use if hole_mc.x = 1080. But by using > some number, you can guarantee a little bit of room between them.

You should add a similar line to the hole mover as well so that it doesn't matter which one gets called first. They both check before they respawn.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I tried your code but when the bird fly through it straight away go to the Game Over page. Why it is happenning?

Comment: It looks like that would only happen if the sheep hits the bird or the hole. The only change I suggested was adding the (if hole_mc.x>1000) line to your birdMove function. I don't know why this would cause a Game Over page.